# Ajaxcontroltoolkit fileupload control

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error message when the Ajaxcontroltoolkit ver. 15.1.4.0  fileupload control is used on a vs2013 web application project with net 4.5.

0x800a138f - javascript runtime error: unable to get property cannotdeserialuzeinvalidjson of undefined or null reference

Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `cannotdeserialuzeinvalidjson` your json is invalid? Please post your json, your matching class and please use CamelCase .. wtf is cannotdeserialuzeinvalidjson? I read it five times till i got it :p

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply and the patience shown. Sorry for inconsistencids  I am a beginner and just trying to figure it out where I could extract details on JSOn and matching class.  The page contains a few textboxes to capture data and insert it into a sql server database besides a ajax file upload control. Nowhere explicitedly hsve I used JSON to serialize/deserialize. Could you please help me in getting the details you hsve asked?